# Error regarding expression_data when using "monocle3"

Tags: r, rna-seq

I have recently started using "monocle3", and  really appreciate all your help in advance!

I am trying to construct single-cell trajectories for my data, but I am encountering the following error and not sure how I can bypass that:

```
cds <- new_cell_data_set(expression_matrix,
                          cell_metadata = cell_metadata,
                          gene_metadata = gene_annotation)
```

> **Error:** Argument expression_data must be a matrix - either sparse from the Matrix package or dense

Prior to this step I have done the following:

```
expression_matrix <- readRDS('C:\\....\\nbt_loc.rds')

cell_metadata <- readRDS('C:\\....\\nbt_loc.rds')

gene_annotation <- readRDS ('C:\\....\\nbt_loc.rds')
```

I really appreciate everyone's input :)

Cheers,

Comment: What is `class(expression_matrix)` ?

Comment: HI FVG, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please make sure to include example data to make your code reproducible. As Bastien suggested, you probably need `is.matrix(expression_matrix)` to be true, if it's not it might be as simple as `as.matrix(expression_matrix)`.

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you so much for your reply. I am  practicing on a pbmc dataset that I got from (https://satijalab.org/seurat/articles/pbmc3k_tutorial.html), and I was just following the steps provided in the monocel3 page to get started (https://cole-trapnell-lab.github.io/monocle3/docs/clustering/). As you advised I first checked the answer to 'is.matrix(expression_matrix)', which came as False. Next, I tried as.matrix(expression_matrix) instead of expression_matrix for cds<- .....  and I got the following error: Error: assert_that: length of assertion is not 1

Comment: @Bastien Ducreux, Hi Bastien, thank you for your reply. I'm not sure if I understand this correctly, but I think  class(expression_matrix) is needed to be assigned when you are using monocle3. (https://cole-trapnell-lab.github.io/monocle3/docs/clustering/)

Comment: I just wanted to know what is the output when you run the code `class(expression_matrix)`but as you mentionned `is.matrix(expression_matrix)`is FALSE so clearly your expression_matrix is not a matrix whereas it should be. We would be pleased to help your but your example is not reproducible as we don't know where `expression_matrix` comes from

Comment: @Bastien Ducreux: sorry for the late reply and thank you so much for trying to help me. So apparently my data was in the form of seurat object and I needed to pull out the parts from the object to make the expression matrix. Thanks again for trying to help me out :)